# Add delay to raw data before send it?

Tags: c++, delay

I want to know how can I add a delay (ex:200ms) to some received raw data before send it again through the network.

Is it possible to use memory to store bits(8000) in memory before send it.

Comment: and miles to go before I 'sleep' :)

Comment: what platform are you programming on?  Windows/Mac OSX/Linux?

Comment: @ Neopallium: It's Win....MVSC++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it is really beyond the scope of this site to give you a full implementation. However here are some tips

Storing memory is basic enough. To store 8000 bits you could use std::bitset or you could manually implement it, no doubt in 1000 bytes on a regular 8 bits-per-byte system. If you need to send it across a network as 8000 bits then the latter form is what you would use but you can get the raw data out of std::bitset so you could still use that class internally.

The delaying is simply a matter of writing a scheduler and std::priority_queue could be used potentially to implement that.

Comment: So it is possible to add delay by just pushing data to memory (ex:8000 bits for a delay of 10ms and a speed of 32kbits/s)..

Comment: @user502951: That would work if your stream is infinite and isosynchronous. Else, what event would trigger sending the last 8000 bits out?

Comment: @MSalters: Do u think there is any other solution to delay the stream before send it again through the network?thanks!

Comment: @fsidiosidi: Of course. Run a timer, and at each clocktick send part of your buffer. But you'll have to be careful with your math. I just noticed a mistake in your previous example: to delay a 32 kbit/sec stream by 10 ms, you must use a 320 bit buffer. If you'd use a 8 kbit buffer, you'd delay the bits by 8000/32 = 250 ms.

Comment: @MSalters: Ok, what if the rate by which we receive data from network is diferent from the one used to send data (poped from the buffer)...let's say that we receive data by 32 kbit/s and then we add a delay of 250 ms...then we send it with 1.5 Mbit/s...do you think it could be possible?

Comment: Obviously, that's not possible. Not at all. You'd buffer 8000 incoming bits in the first 250 ms, but within 6 ms you'd have emptied that buffer sending at 1,5 Mbps.

Answer (score 1):

You do not store or send 8000bits to cause a delay.  Either use the usleep()/nanosleep() functions to pause the program for 200ms before sending the data.

Or use the [Win32 Timer API](http://www.suite101.com/content/using-the-win32-timer-api-a23678) SetTimer/KillTimer.  Add the data you want to delay to a queue and then start a timer for the number of milliseconds you want to delay the data.  When the timer goes off, remove the data from the queue and send it.

Comment: I don't want to stop the program...i want him still receiving from the network...and add the delay to the data (in real time) and after that start sending the data over the network again...

Comment: I did found the solution...by using 2 threads one receive data from network and push it to the queue and the other pops the data from the queue and send it to the network..and by making the second sleep for a while I can a delay....but the problem is that I have receiving rate (32 kbit/s) != of the sending rate (1.5 Mbits/s)

Comment: your sending rate can't be larger then your receiving rate, not unless you are adding data or uncompressing the received data.